# Can I use jquery in a handlebars helper?

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

I am trying to write a handlebars helper which creates buttons that call a javascript method. I was trying to do this with a jQuery event listener, but it doesn't seem to be working. Can anyone could tell me if I improperly wrote the event listener, or if it just can't be done in a handlebars helper?

Here's the helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('viewBookLink', function(book) {

            $(document).ready(function () { 
                $("#link" + book.bookId).click(function() {
                    myapp.book.getBook(book.bookId);
                });
            });

             return new Handlebars.SafeString("<button class=\"btn btn-link\" id=\"link" + book.bookId + "\">" +
                    book.localizations.en_US.bookName + "</button>");
        });
```

And here's the method the click is supposed to be calling:

```
book : {
        getBook : function(bookId) {
            alert("tried to get book with id: " + bookId);
        }
    },
```

(Both these being inside the myapp namespace.)

When I click the button, the `getBook` function never fires. If I have to, I'll just create the button with an `onClick`, but I wanted to see if I could go the event listener route first.

Comment: You probably have an order of execution problem. You don't have much control over the order of your `$(document).ready` callback and when the template's HTML is in the DOM and Handlebars just works with text so you can't use the usual "localize `$` to a specific element" trick. I think the delegation form of jQuery's `on` would serve you better, functionality like this doesn't work well with a templating system.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm a bit of a jquery newb and couldn't figure out what you meant by "the delegation form of jQuery's `on`." Could you give an example?

Comment: See http://api.jquery.com/delegate/ and http://api.jquery.com/on/, basically bind your handlers to a parent element outside the template so your problem goes away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I pretty much did what mu is too short suggested.

Here's an example:

```
$("#bookTemplateDiv").on("click", "#addButton", function() {
    $("#bookNames").append(myapp.consts.bookStuffTemplate({}));
});
```